# Who knows an algorithm for k soundness verification?

Tags: workflow, petri-net

I have a workflow net (petri net) and I have to implement an algorithm to verify if it is k sound correct.

Answer (score 0):

You know, there is just an [awful lot of work](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=petri+net+k+soundness) on that recently.

[This paper](http://www.ijcis.info/Vol5N1/pp%2051-61.pdf) includes an algorithm for deciding k-soundness.  But be cautious, because [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.143.1893&rep=rep1&type=pdf) indicates that k-soundness in the presence of certain extensions is undecidable.